# Is It Possible To Install Another Switch To Control Fan?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

Is it possible for me to install another switch to control the fan? This switch controls the light/fan. However, if the switch is off neither the light or fan can operate. I would like to separate these controls if possible. I don't know what the white wire is that comes in, goes into the wire nut, and then goes out as two wires.

I believe there's really only 3 wires to use here. The ground on the left of the switch, the power coming in on the bottom right of the switch (wire cut so looks like 2 wires), and the power going to the fan on the top right of the switch. Unless I can use the white wire somehow?

[image: I believe there's really only 3 wires to use here. The ground on the left of the switch, the power coming in on the bottom right of the switch (wire cut so looks like 2 wires), and the power going to the fan on the top right of the switch]

Comment: Are you OK with having a full dimmer/fan-controller here?  Is there a remote in the existing fan, or is it controlled via pull chains at the moment?

Comment: Oh yes so I would actually like another rocker switch like the one that is there currently. If it can be wired up to two switches, I would cut the hole larger to fit another switch. There is no remote, it is currently controlled via pull chains. Thanks.

Comment: Is installing a module in the fan canopy an option for you?  Or is pulling a new cable between the switch and the fan an option, for that matter?

Comment: You can only  control the fan and light separately with wall rocker switches by adding another wire up the wall and to the fixture.

Comment: @Kris [that is false](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003ZUXSYC/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_gL0ZBb5AKCDCQ) edit: well re-reading what you typed it’s accurate, it’s not rocket switches.

Comment: i would get a new fan with a remote, or options to have wireless wall switches that switch it

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/PECHAM-Universal-Wireless-Application-Restaurant/dp/B00W5UC7B8.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the black wires. It looks to me like **3** wires, which would match the **3** white neutral wires and possibly give more options here. You said "wire cut so looks like 2 wires" which doesn't make much sense to me. If it is actually 2 blacks (from the switch) and 2 whites (from the wire nut) going to the fan then it may be split at the fan for fan vs. light and everything would be great for adding a 2nd switch. On the other hand, maybe there is no 2nd black going from the switch OR maybe the extra white & black are going someplace else (e.g., switched outlet somewhere).

Comment: Basically what I was trying to explain is that the two black wires you see going out on the right side were at one point one wire. In other switches in the house, it looks like they looped that wire around the screw, but on this one the wire was  cut and both ends "join" back together through the screw.... if that helps clarify anything.

Comment: I think that's the power coming in, going into the switch, and then the power goes out to other switches on the circuit. So in essence it's one power wire.

Comment: A picture of what's at the fan would help, but assuming there's only 1 yellow Romex, you're stuck without using a wireless application like linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have "Romex" (NM) wiring now, so you don't have the option, at least not easily, to run another wire to go to the fan.  If you have normal metal conduit, you could use a "fish line" to pull another wire.  If that were the case, you could swap out the current switch with a "double" switch without changing the box.

But, this can sometimes be tricky in any case, since you don't always have a straight shot from your switch to your fan (which may well have been wired intended to only be a light fixture).

The 2nd white wire coming out is a mystery to me.  White wires are typically the "neutral", so having it come in to this box and then go back out (with the wirenut to connect) makes sense.  But it's odd that there would be a second one in the current cable coming in -- if the cable did have 3 wires plus ground, they would normally be, for examample, white, black, and red.